# Zend 3 stylesheet not included in IE

Tags: css, zend-framework3

In my `zend 3` project stylesheets is good included in Chrome and firefox (and all others), only IE is not including the stylesheet...

```
<!-- Le styles -->
<?= $this
    ->headLink(['rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/icon.png'])
    ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/style_algemeen.css?id=28'))
    ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/bootstrap.min.css'))
?>
```

http://maintenanceplus.nl/

Comment: What do you mean by "the stylesheet is not included"? I opened the link you gave, and the look is the same on both Chrome, Edge and IE. Stylesheet are there in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the 8 digit color code (eg #016e95ff) was the problem. IE is not happy with that! After going back to 6 digits #016e95 the problem was gone

Comment: Don't think non-IE browsers are the issue here. What they're doing is something not part of the RGB-color standard, defined in the W3C recommendation. IE is the only one [following the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#rgb-color). That IE strictly follows the standard is a very good reason to also test in IE if something works.